# How can I silence a PyCharm "Unexpected argument" message for simple, indirect object creation

Tags: python, pycharm, python-dataclasses

I am getting an "Unexpected argument" message with Python 3.7 and PyCharm 2020.2 when using the code below.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo(object):
    x: int
    y: str
        
        
arg_dict = {'x': 1, 'y': 'bar'}

the_class = Foo

a = Foo(**arg_dict)

b = the_class(**arg_dict)
```

How can I prevent it or silence it?

Comment: Works fine for me with the same setup.  Can you please provide the full text of the error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: Works fine for me as well

Comment: There is no stack trace. The message appears in the PyCharm Problems window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the warning by using

```
# noinspection PyArgumentList
```

on the line before it occurs.

The various possible `noinspection`s are not properly documented by JetBrains, which is why I find the following list useful: https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to silence these on a per-project basis by going to

```
File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > [search/select: 'Incorrect call arguments']
```

In the "Severity by Scope" corner, change the scope to "Project Files" and set the severity to "Typo".